# How can I use an extended height Toolbar with menu navigation and actions centered vertically?

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I'd like to have a non-standard height toolbar which has centered buttons and navigation, but I can't get it to work. I use this example layout:

```
<Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_regular"
    android:background="#777"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp" />
```

And it ends up looking like this:

[image: Extended Height Toolbar With Uncentered Buttons]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Per a [conversation on G+ with Chris Banes](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+ChrisBanes/posts/MVugxgjzkDx), you can use minHeight to define the constrained height for actions and buttons. This value defaults to *?attr/actionBarSize* on Toolbar. So, I used the layout

```
<Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_regular"
    android:background="#777"
    android:minHeight="100dp"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp" />
```

to get this appearance:

[image: Extended Height Toolbar With Uncentered Buttons]